# Microsoft graph api- Filtering on attached file extensions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am using ms graph api to get all the messages with attachments. Over this I need to get the files having docx/pdf extensions. Below are the filters I have tried.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=hasAttachments eq true and ext eq 'docx'

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=hasAttachments eq true and extensions eq 'docx'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to do this using multiple API calls. First you need to retrieve a list of [messages](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message) with attachments (`has Attachments`) and then you need to iterate over the resulting `id`s in order to retrieve the attachment metadata.

For example, the call returns a list of message ids that have attachments:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=hasAttachments eq true&$select=id`

For each of the IDs we got back, we then make a second call to get the attachments:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{message id}/attachments`

From these results you can inspect the [Attachment's](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/attachment) `name` property to determine what the file extension is.

Comment: You could `$expand=attachments` to include them in a single call